# How to scan BLE devices in Android without giving location permission?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

**Description:**
I am scanning the nearby `BLE devices` in my android application and allowing users for these permissions `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` which requires enabling location in the Android device.

**What I am looking for**:
I need to remove the location permission from the app to scan nearby devices.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 12 and higher, you should be able to [use `BLUETOOTH_SCAN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#BLUETOOTH_SCAN) as the permission.

On older devices, you have no choice but to request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. You do not need `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

Comment: I am using api version 33 and I cannot find any devices without requesting fine location permission. There is no error though when scanning. (I am scanning with an uuid filter). With fine location it can scan for my device successfully

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to do what you are trying to achieve. for more information check the android developer documentation.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview